# Multiple Ads on the same project

Tags: swift, ads

I've worked all day trying to put another Ads on my swift project. I dont know if its a xcode bug or not but when I add GoogleMobileAds together with UnityAds or AdColony, this error appears. I'm importing all frameworks properly following each of Ads instructions. Does anybody got the same problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have not added enough information to your question for us to answer it.  How is the ad framework being added to the project?  Are you using Cocoapods?  Is your application linking with the framework?

Comment: I'm adding the framework through Build Phases: Link with Libraries
I'm not using Cocoapods

Maybe I got your last question right: Apparently the application is not linking with the framework because that error shows up